# Why is .Contains not functioning as expected?

Tags: c#, vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

I'm translating some code from C# to VB.NET and getting an odd problem. I have a class that takes an array of URls as strings and checks them against a given request to build a route. Here's the C# code:

```
string requestedurl = httpContext.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionfilePath;
if (urls.Contains(requestedurl, StringCompraer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) {
    //Do stuff
    }
```

I've translated it into this:

```
Dim requestedurl As String = httpContext.Request.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath
If urls.Contains(requestedurl, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) = True Then
    'Do stuff
End If
```

The urls array contains a couple of strings beginning with '~/' and the requestedurl is '~/' so that should be a match. However the code above never executes the 'do stuff' section.

As an alternative I tried this which works fine:

```
For Each url As String In urls
    If url.ToLower.Contains(requestedurl.ToLower) = True Then
        'Do stuff
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Why is the Contains extension in the first example functioning differently than the String.Contains method in the second and is there a better way to translate this?

Comment: There should be no difference.

Comment: I know! It's totally odd.

Comment: Compile both snippets in a console app. Then look at the IL/code in a decompiler. Perhaps that will point out the error.

Comment: Show how you declared `urls` in both cases

Comment: This is off topic, but why do you feel that you require " = True" for the VB version? It's just as redundant as it " == true" would be in C#.

Comment: It's not redundant if you want to make absolutely clear what your intent is. Missing off the '= true' bit (in either language) is, in my opinion (since you asked for it), a bad habit that makes for less readable and maintainable code. Explicit code is better than implicit code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The urls array contains a couple of strings beginning with '~/' and the requestedurl is '~/' so that should be a match." -> No, it shouldn't. Contains checks for absolute matches, and not if any of the strings in the array contain that string. The Contains extension method on arrays only checks whole strings, as opposed to the Contains method on string, which checks to see if a string contains the substring you're looking for. That's exactly why your second example works.

This will output nothing:

```
string[] urls = { "bla", "~/something/some_folder", "ab", "cd", "~/some_file" };
string requestedUrl = "~/";
if (urls.Contains(requestedUrl, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Check");
}
```

whereas this:

```
string[] urls = { "bla", "~/something/some_folder", "~/", "~/", "~/some_file" };
string requestedUrl = "~/";
if (urls.Contains(requestedUrl, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Check");
}
```

Will output check. If that's your 1:1 code conversion, the original doesn't work.

You can leverage Linq to your needs if you want to avoid the loop by using something like:

```
if (urls.Any(url => url.Contains(requestedUrl)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Check");
}
```

You'll have to do the conversion to VB.Net by yourself, as I'm not familiar with the language.

Comment: This explains why snippet 3 works in the question but not why snippet 1 and 2 behave differently

Comment: I doubt they behave differently, as snippet 1 doesn't work the way the asker intended.

Comment: I agree - my comment was more for the OP than yourself as 1 and 2 *should* behave identically

Comment: Snippet 1 is from a book not a live project. I think the intention in the book was that it works as designed it's my mistake in not realising that the two different versions of .Contains function differently